# <a> Link is invisible on IE8 but visible on FF, Chrome etc

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Please check: http://test.internet.az.pl/panel/lost_password2.php

Link: "Powrót do strony logowania Powrót do strony logowania" is properly visible on Firefox, Chrome etc. while it's not visible on IE8 (it's way higher).

How to correct this ?

```
        <div class="lost_password" style="float:right; margin-top:-27px; margin-left:25px">
    <a class="a" href="index.php">
    <span>Powrót do strony logowania</span> <img alt="Powrót do strony logowania" src="gfx/arrow.png" />
    </a>
```

Comment: *"Please check: `http://test.internet.az.pl/panel/lost_password2.php`"* - Um, no. Post your code; that's where the truth lies.

Comment: There's no PHP in your code, so the `php` tag doesn't apply.

Comment: I think that's the problem: margin-top:-27px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came because of the floating element.

Instead of this

```
<div class="lost_password" style="float:right; margin-top:-27px; margin-left:25px">
```

Use like this.

```
 <div class="lost_password" style="margin-top:-27px; margin-left:135px">
```